# Why is the wheel package not installed by default in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-wheel

Here is my problem: I need to distribute Python packages that I created. I would like to create wheels, as this is now the preferred way of distributing Python packages.

On my machine: no problem.

On my client server, however, I do not have control over the Python (3.6.3) used to create the wheels. And - surprise! - the wheel package is not included by default in Python 3.6!

And yes, I know I can do: `sudo pip install wheel` but I do not have sudo rights in that environment.

I could create a virtualenv, install wheel in that virtual environment, ans then create my packages (and I will probably end up doing just that), but what a pain in the neck!!

Am I missing something here?

If not, there is an inconsistency, in my mind: on the one hand, we are told to use wheels, but on the other hand the "preferred" mechanism is not available in a vanilla Python (at least in Python 3.6)

Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a an intermediate between installing packages system-wise via `sudo pip` and installing in virtual environment: install packages for *your user*!

```
$ pip --user install --upgrade pip wheel
```

*(in some platforms `pip` automatically selects `--user` when invoked without `sudo`)*

Packages that ship binaries (such as `pip` and `wheel`) will have them installed by default at `~/.local/bin`, so make sure that dir is in your `$PATH`. The default `/etc/profile` or `~/.profile` in most distros already do that if dir exists, so you might have to logout/login once for `$PATH` to be updated after installing your first package.

Now you can enjoy `wheel` (and latest `pip`) just like as if they were any other system package, and without any the of trouble of dealing with virtualenvs.